# Making getContentResolver() to work in class extending Fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

What I have in mind is to use two fragments, first one to show the contacts list and second one to show the details of contact which is being selected in the upper fragment.
The class that I'm using to extend the **Fragment** class does not allow me to use `getContentResolver()` method due to the context issue. Now I'm trying to fetch the contact in the same class which is extending Fragment class and use it to show in the list view and its details. After going through some older solution I found the way to create a function and pass Context to it as a parameter but the problem is I don't have to call it from any other class which is extending Activity. I want to do it from that same class extending Fragment.

How should I do this?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `getActivity().getContentResolver();` doesn't do the trick ?

Comment: Nope. Neither `getActivity()` nor `getApplicationContext()` is working.

Comment: @AhmedAbidi Yes it did the trick for me and its the correct way too, Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to add this code to a previous activity:

```
// a static variable to get a reference of our application context
public static Context contextOfApplication;
public static Context getContextOfApplication()
{
return contextOfApplication;
}
```

and in the same activity, in your onCreate method add this line:

```
 contextOfApplication = getApplicationContext();
```

In your fragment you can access this by using :

```
Context applicationContext = YourActivity.getContextOfApplication();
applicationContext.getContentResolver();
```

Comment: Great! I haven't tried this but I'm sure that this will work. I was thinking something like this to use a getter function for the context.

Thanks a ton to all of them who tried to help.

Answer (score 10):

Getting the application context using getter doesn't work. The equivalent of above answer is

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
```

Answer (score 8):

When using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`:

`getActivity().getContentResolver()`

Answer (score 2):

**For kotlin users-**

```
activity!!.contentResolver
```

**but what worked for me-**

```
  requireActivity().contentResolver
```

You can use whatever work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with a fragment, but tried

```
(getContext().getContentResolver(), filePath);
```

Comment: Should've explained what is the change and why, as a similar comment was posted on the question earlier!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (requestCode == GALLERY) {


        if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            if (data!=null) {
                 Uri uri = data.getData();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
                    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
                    //imageofpic.setImageBitmap(image);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this.

```
  Cursor contctCursorVar = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contctDataVar, null,
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.