# contentresolver unexpected in fragment kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

//Hello good afternoon guys i am newbie in developer android, I want get device id inside on fragment , but get Content Resolver has unexpected, how to resolve this?,i have tested before inside main activity its show and no problem, bu i have problem while show device id inside fragment, need help guys, thank you very much. below my code to get device id

```
val device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
            )
```

Comment: You can try to call `getActivity().getContentResolver()`

Comment: ok i will try sir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making getContentResolver() to work in class extending Fragment class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852653/making-getcontentresolver-to-work-in-class-extending-fragment-class)

Comment: var device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(
 getActivity()?.getContentResolver(),
 Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
) i try this code but crash sir while open fragment with error log contentresolver.getuserid() on a null object reference

Comment: var device_id = Settings.Secure.getString(
 getActivity()?.getApplicationContext()?.getContentResolver(),
 Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
) i try your reference with added applicationcontext but same crash sir

Comment: need help :((...

Comment: val device_id: String?
  get() {
   try {
    return Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity()?.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
   } catch (e: Exception) {
    e.fillInStackTrace()
   }

 return null
  } this is for kotlin its work